# Pdf document as response for ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, pdf, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I need a script that passes a json string to a function in the controller and process the response pdf document to be seen as downloads to the user.

I return a pdf document of FileResult data type in c# as the response for an ajax call which passes a JSON string to the function.
I need this pdf document to be seen as downloads to the user. How can I perform this? I tried to write code in the success of ajax but the control goes to error and by debugging I found it to be a parse error.

**Ajax code is like**

```
function Download(){
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "{url to the action}",
        data: {
            //Send json data that you want
        }
        success:function (e){
            alert('success');
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("error");
        }
    })

}
```

**C# code is like:**

```
public FileResult getPDF(string statementHTML)
{ 

//code to convert to pdf file
File file = //pdf document with MIME 'apllication/pdf'
return file;
}
```

When the above code executes the error alert is invoked but this c# function returns a pdf document but seems like ajax don't accept it.

Comment: show your code, perhaps we can assist you

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I have added it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to ajax to make this download call, you can just do this.

```
function DownloadFile(){
    //do some calculation
    window.location="{url to the action}?argument1=value1&argument2=value2....."
}
```

However if you have to do it via ajax, you can get [download.js](http://danml.com/download.html) and do this.

```
function DownloadFileUsingAjax(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "{url to the action}",
        data: {
            //Send json data that you want
        }
    })
    .done(function(data){
        //download function is from download.js
        download(data, fileName, fileMimeType);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For another way, you could try mock the button click event to download the file like

Client Side.

```
@section Scripts{ 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/GetPDF',
                method: 'get',
                contentType:'application/json',
                xhrFields: {
                    responseType: 'blob'
                },
                success: function (data, status, response) {
                    var filename = "";
                    var disposition = response.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
                    if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
                        var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
                        var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
                        if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
                    }
                    let a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
                    a.download = filename;
                    document.body.append(a);
                    a.click();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Controller

```
public FileResult GetPDF(string statementHTML)
{
    var fileByte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"xxx\Test.pdf");
    return File(fileByte, "apllication/pdf", "Test.pdf");
}
```